# Как сохранить в переменную сообщение отправленное боту?

Tags: python

недавно мы с моим другом создали сервер в discord, и поскольку создавать эмбеды самостоятельно не законно, я создаю для этого бота, его задачей должно быть написать команду через префикс, затем 3 аргумента name text и color (!эмбед текст описание цвет)
Я не понимаю, как это сделать. Есть ли здесь те, кто это понимает как это сделать.
Код:

```
import TOKEN

import discord

from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def привет(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Привет')




@client.event
async def on_message( message ):

    if message.author == client.user:

        msg = message.content.lower()
        msg_list = msg.split()
        msg = msg_list
       
@bot.command()
async def эмбед(ctx, text):
    titl = 
    tet = 
    clr = 
    embed = discord.Embed(title = titl, description = tet, color = clr)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)



bot.run(TOKEN.token)
```

Comment: рекомендую: 1) перевести все на русский тут, иначе ничего не понятно русскоязычной аудитории будет. 2) выучить английский, а пока Google Translate использовать, иначе ничего не понятно англоязычной аудитории будет.

Comment: зачем вернули английский язык? вам же переоткрывают вопрос. Откатил к последней версии на русском